# Android ListView Scroll Down

Tags: android, scroll

I have a media player in a service and it sends messages to my activity where a `ListView` is hosted. Let's say I have 100 songs in the `ListView`, and every time I select a song, the background of that row changes. I need the selected row to be always visible on screen. The problem I have right now, is that my service goes to the next song after the current song is completed, and it selects that row. However, it doesn't scroll down when the selected song is not visible on screen. I need it to auto scroll when it detects that the current song is the last song that a user can see on his screen.

This is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_song"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_singer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_song" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below the code from my activity. I have a handler in my service class that sends a message to the activity when the song is completed and goes to the next song.

```
private void updateUI(Intent serviceIntent){
    int songPos = serviceIntent.getIntExtra("songpos", 0);
    mListSongs.setItemChecked(songPos, true);
    //mListSongs.setSelection(songPos);
}
```

If I use the `mListSongs.setSelection(songPos)`, the song will always be selected on top, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ListView.smoothScrollToPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)) for that.

> The view will scroll such that the indicated position is displayed.

```
private void updateUI(Intent serviceIntent){
    int songPos = serviceIntent.getIntExtra("songpos", 0);
    mListSongs.setItemChecked(songPos, true);
    mListSongs.smoothScrollToPosition(songPos);
}
```